# Could a nanoscopic grain of tungsten moving at ludicrous speed make a sonic boom?

Tags: acoustics, nanoscience

Writing a scifi story about a civilization with mature nanotechnology. Grain of tungsten is a proxy for a nanite.

If such a tiny thing as a nanogram of tungsten somehow got accelerated to some truly ludicrous speed, like the speed to achieve orbit, say 11km/s - would it make a sonic boom? Or would it melt into a little spray of sub-atomic particles before getting to orbit?

Comment: From XKCD, [What would happen if you tried to hit a baseball pitched at 90% the speed of light?](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/)

Comment: Thanks, @mmesser314. Saw that when it came out, but it talks about an event at both a vastly different scale and speed.

Answer (score 1):

One nanogram is 1E-12 kg, a tungsten grain of that mass would have dimensions around 0.004 milimeters, which is extremely small, like droplets in a cloud. Even at speed of 11km/s, its energy is only 0.00006 Joules. For comparison, energy of a bullet shot from a gun is in the realm of hundreds of Joules.

Energy 0.00006 J is pretty much what would be needed to vaporize the grain. But not all kinetic energy goes into vaporization, because vaporization stops below some speed, and even while it happens, some of the energy heats up the air, some of it just increases temperature of the tungsten. So not all of the grain would vaporize, only some part of it. How big a part is hard to estimate without more complex analysis.

Most probably, the grain would produce a long light track like meteorites do and after it slows down its remains would silently fall down.

How visible/audible would be the track? Most probably like meteorites, not much in a sunny day, but should be noticeable during night.

If you want a bigger spectacular show for sure at that speed, the tungsten piece has to be many times bigger, in the range of centimeters/meters.

Answer (score 1):

I estimated the distance at which the tungsten grain will evaporate, I used other people's method described in my answer at [Could the end cap of the Pascal B (1) survive its trip through the atmosphere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/488151/could-the-end-cap-of-the-pascal-b-1-survive-its-trip-through-the-atmosphere/489471) , the distance is 1.4 cm (order of magnitude estimate). This is comparable to the sound wavelength at 20 kHz. The evaporated tungsten grain will heat a small volume to high temperatures, so there will be a shock wave. Further calculations are needed to estimate at what distance this shock wave would be audible. One can get a general idea using the results of the article "Photoacoustic breakdown sound source in air" (Ultrasonics 1994 Vol 32 No 5 327).